# Using tdqm with GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tqdm

I am trying to use `GradientBoostingClassifier`, but it's taking a long time. I'd really like to implement some sort of progress bar using `tdqm`, but I have no earthly idea on how to make it work with my code below:

```
modelClf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=58)
modelClf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = modelClf.predict(X_test)
scores.loc['ROC-AUC','3'] = (roc_auc_score(y, modelClf.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]))
scores.loc['Accuracy','3'] = (accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

`scores` is a small dataframe for comparing ROC-AUC and accuracy outputs between different methods.

Everything that I've found revolves around loops, but I couldn't make it work for my task. I've also tried turning on verbose, but it doesn't really help determine how long it will be.

Is it possible to make a `tdqm` progress bar for my code? I work in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Have you tried just adding `verbose=1` as a parameter to your model: `modelClf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=58), verbose=1)`?

Comment: I have, and it does indicate that the code is working but it does not help with getting an idea oh how long it's going to take

Comment: `verbose=2` will also print time remaining.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I'll just be patient and go walk the dog while it's classifying :)